# Gmaps4Rails - auto-adjusting map to bounds not respecting hidden markers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

Using Gmaps4Rails, I've got some markers that I can show/hide based on an attribute. That works fine. However, I'm trying to get the map to auto-adjust to the current set of markers with `Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds()` called after I set the currently visible markers.

Whenever I filter items, the entire map shows, as if it were displaying all of the markers, even though it actually displays just the filtered ones. I *think* it is because it considers hidden markers when setting the bounds, but I could be wrong!

Here is my filtering code:

```
$("select").change(->
    currentFilters = $('select').val()
    hideAllMarkers()
    visibleMarkers()
    Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds()
  )

  visibleMarkers = ->
    filtered = Gmaps.map.markers
    filtered = _.filter(filtered, (marker) ->
      _.include(currentFilters, marker.market)
    )

    _.each filtered, (marker) ->
      Gmaps.map.showMarker marker

  hideAllMarkers = ->
    _.each Gmaps.map.markers, (marker) ->
      Gmaps.map.hideMarker marker
```

And here are the options I'm initializing the map with:

```
@gmap_options = {"map_options" => {
  "auto_zoom" => true,
  "auto_adjust" => true,
  "mapTypeControl" => true,
  "detect_location" => true,
  "center_on_user" => true},
  "markers" => {"data" => @map}
}
```

Comment: please open an issue on the gem's github page, I should add this feature... or consider pulling it!

Comment: I 'fixed' it with one line in the Google Map coffee file - just setting the bounds based on visible markers, not hidden ones. Will submit a pull request with that fix and an additional configuration option in the json.

Comment: any follow up on this?  care to show what line you added to the coffee file?

Comment: @apneadiving did you add this as an actual feature?  I've looked through your entire code, and didn't notice it.  I could have completely missed it, obviously, though.

Comment: Never did submit a pull. However, you can find my change [here.](https://github.com/chrismanderson/ls_find_your_adventure/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js.coffee#L189) Just check `marker.serviceObject.visible`.